# How to read all images from iphone photo library into application and how i would i get path of photo library?

Tags: iphone

How to read all images from iphone photo library into  application and how i would i get path of photo library??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read all images from iPhone photo library, use the "assets library framework".

You can check out Apple's documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html

There is a ALAssetsFilter called "allPhotos", you can use the filter with the setAssetsFilter: and the enumerateAssetsUsingBlock: methods in ALAssetsGroup to achieve this.

Here is some sample code implementing this:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/