# UIImagePicker slideshow of images on selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, slideshow

Like the Photos App shows, all albums > all photos in a particular album > single photo view,

even I need a similar kind of a view. I have used `UIImagePickerController` and easily go to the second step. However, whenever I select an image, I can not show a slide show kind of a view, as `UIImagePicker` does not give me that.

I made another view controller , just to display these images in a pagenation form.

But, from the delegate method, `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, when an image is selected, I get only that image using:

```
[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

How do I know the images next to this image, and before this image, so that I can create a slide show?

Comment: I ran into same problem while ago and I try ELCAlbumViewer from github and With some modification I am able to generate the same what you want :) so give a try to it :)

Comment: Give try to this [github](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) this will give you the basic Idea how to give it start

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7297703/1132951) also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302035/1132951) as it contains some code samples also

Comment: Hi have put one dem project [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/demoGallery) May this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722). To obtain a list of images or videos in the Photo library you would use the `enumerateGroupsUsingTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` method of an `ALAssetsLibrary` object. For instance, you could call this method, then as it asynchronously returns images and video you would build your array of images for the slideshow view.

Also check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177606/iphone-get-uiimagepickercontroller-lat-lng). The answer shows how to get an ALAsset object from the `UIImagePickerController`, which lets you find the URL of the image and other info about it.

Comment: I know about ALAssetLibrary, I do not want to recreate what apple has given, I just want an extra slide show view