# How to open camera roll and slide show saved photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7.1

I am developing a app in which i capture a image and save image into gallery.After that i open the gallery now i want to view full screen slide show of saved images.

Am using the following code it just open the image full screen with choose and cancel options but i need slide show.

```
pickerview.allowsEditing=YES; 

pickerview.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 

[self presentViewController:pickerview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePicker slideshow of images on selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360209/uiimagepicker-slideshow-of-images-on-selection)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
picturePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picturePicker.mediaTypes =[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
picturePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentViewController:picturePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
```